# How to set a column x with the value x+y in Oracle?

Tags: oracle11g

I wanted the exact syntax for the following operation

```
UPDATE table1
SET colx= colx+y
WHERE ..some condtion..
```

Note: colx and y are of the type NUMBERs

Thanks,
Amrutha

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can format source code with the `{}` toolbar button. I've done it for you this time.

Comment: What is wrong with your current syntax? Are you getting an error? If so, what error are you getting? What is your WHERE clause? Please post useful examples of the problem you are trying to solve and then we can help you better.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is already correct.  For example:

```
update emp
set    sal = sal + 1000
where  empno = 1234;
```